# Oracle Log Miner - size of operation

Tags: oracle

Some background information at first: I'm currently analysing load on Oracle database from .Net application which make use of NServiceBus. We've observed high redo logs activity when running application and hence - high amount of archivelog (we've got database in archivelog mode). We've used Toad Logminer to find out what causes it, unfortunately many of the operations are of type UNSUPPORTED. I've assume it's because of using securefile type of LOB. However I've digged into database to Logminer view: v$logmnr_contents to see there is a lot more columns than in Toad's Logminer.

What I need is size of each operation in redo. Here's my query so far:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP,
       RBABYTE,
       SEG_OWNER,
       SEG_NAME,
       TABLE_NAME,
       SEG_TYPE,
       SEG_TYPE_NAME,
       TABLE_SPACE,
       ROW_ID,
       OPERATION,
       SQL_REDO
  FROM V$LOGMNR_CONTENTS
 WHERE 1 = 1 AND OPERATION = 'UNSUPPORTED'
```

I'm not sure if RBABYTE is correct value to use or maybe calculation is more complicated, for me it looks like record size including LOB. Oracle's documentations says it's "RBA byte offset within the block", but it's not enough.
Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
with t1 as
        (select rs_id,
                ssn,
                rbablk,
                rbabyte,
                rbablk * 512 + rbabyte curpos,
                lead (rbablk * 512 + rbabyte, 1, rbablk * 512 + rbabyte)
                   over (partition by substr (rs_id, 1, 9)order by
                            rbasqn,
                            rbablk,
                            rbabyte,
                            scn,
                            redo_value)
                   nextpos,
                  lead (rbablk * 512 + rbabyte, 1, rbablk * 512 + rbabyte)
                     over (partition by substr (rs_id, 1, 9)order by
                              rbasqn,
                              rbablk,
                              rbabyte,
                              scn,
                              redo_value)
                - (rbablk * 512 + rbabyte)
                   redo_size,
                operation,
                case
                   when operation = 'INTERNAL' and data_obj# != 0 then
                      (select t0.owner
                         from dba_objects t0
                        where t0.object_id = t1.data_obj#)
                   else
                      seg_owner
                end
                   seg_owner,
                case
                   when operation = 'INTERNAL' and data_obj# != 0 then
                      (select t0.object_name nome
                         from dba_objects t0
                        where t0.object_id = t1.data_obj#)
                   else
                      seg_name
                end
                   seg_name,
                sql_redo,
                redo_value,
                client_id,
                timestamp
           from v$logmnr_contents t1)
  select rs_id,
         ssn,
         rbablk,
         rbabyte,
         curpos,
         nextpos,
         redo_size,
         seg_owner,
         seg_name,
         operation,
         sql_redo
    from t1
order by substr (rs_id, 1, 9),
         ssn,
         rbablk,
         rbabyte,
         redo_value
```